# Java and Generic Classes

Tags: java, generics

What does this work without a type?

```
ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
```

Does it just default to type object if you don't specify a type, and that cast everything to object?

And what does it mean in the api when it says ClassType (won't display) a question mark within less than greater than signs.

Comment: I think it defaults to type `Object`, which every other class in Java inherits.

Comment: @bdares: no, `ArrayList` is not the same as `ArrayList<Object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Does it just default to type object if you don't specify a type, and that cast everything to object?**

Yes. That's almost* right.

A generic type (such as `ArrayList`) which is not provided with type parameters is called a *raw type*. Raw types are covered in the official trail [Type Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> *For instance, `Box<String>` is translated to type `Box`, which is called the raw type — a raw type is a generic class or interface name without any type arguments. This means that you can't find out what type of Object a generic class is using at runtime.*
>
> [...]
>
> *Type erasure exists so that new code may continue to interface with legacy code. **Using a raw type for any other reason is considered bad programming practice and should be avoided whenever possible.***

*) You can put any `Object` into an `ArrayList`, but as @newacct points out in the comments, `ArrayList` is not to be considered *the same as* `ArrayList<Object>`, since `ArrayList` (and `ArrayList<?>` btw) are both supertypes of `ArrayList<WhatEver>`, while `ArrayList<Object>` is not.

Comment: What does it mean when in the api it says has a question mark as a generic type?

Comment: `ArrayList<?>` is the super type of `ArrayList<WhatEverYouLike>`, i.e., it can be used as type of a parameter in which you don't know what the array list contains. You can read more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: When I use Class.forName("Class"), it supposed to return a class with a specified generic type Class>?< (reversed them can't get them to display) But is seems evetyone just uses class.  Is that the same thing?

Comment: No, strictly speaking `Class<?>` is not the same as `Class`. Have a look at [What is the difference between the unbounded wildcard parameterized type and the raw type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ303)

Comment: Thank you so much for that reference, it was very clear.  So I assume it would be better to use Class>?< for future compatibility? And both without the >?< and with the >?< both return a reference as type object?

Comment: Well, the rule is, prefer `<?>` over raw types, but avoid `<?>` if you know the actual type. (To format `<` and `>` surround them backticks :-)

Comment: "Does it just default to type object if you don't specify a type ... Yes. That's right." `ArrayList` is not the same as `ArrayList<Object>`. For example, the compiler will allow you to pass an `ArrayList<String>` in to something that expects a raw `ArrayList`, but it won't allow you to pass it to something that expects an `ArrayList<Object>`

Answer (score 7):

That's called a *raw type*. Avoid raw types where possible, as they reduce type safety.

Basically they're there for backward compatibility, so that when generics were introduced, existing code still compiled. As ever, see the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#Raw%20Types) for more details.

Note that using a raw type is *not* the same as using a type with a type argument of `Object`, as raw types have *all traces* of generics removed from their effective API - even generic methods using *other* type parameters. That's part of what makes them dangerous.

Comment: +1: I never thought of generic methods in raw types being treated that way... Good hint

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

This is how Java used to work before generics were introduced.  And in fact, this is *still* how it works, under the hood.  The compiler performs basic type-checking, and then performs *type erasure*, so the bytecode that you're left with will be identical to that of the above.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that generics is enforced at compile time, not runtime

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a zip file in the root of the directory where you installed your JDK. In there, there is an src.zip.

I use eclipse as an IDE. In that [you can attach the source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=499365) so when you push CTRL+SHIFT+T and type ArrayList you'll be able to see it's source yourself ;)
Actually it is also a good way to see how more expert ppl write source-code :)